# Implement Pdf Reader with Search Functionality Android

Tags: android, pdf, mobile, pdf-viewer

I have to create a PDF reader for android with searching functionality.
I searched a lot on internet and lots of link found for PDF reader like :

https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview
http://androiddeveloperspot.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-pdf-reader-open-source-code.html

but anyone does not functionality to searching and highlighting the searched text.

I would like to know whether it is possible or not in android and if possible then how.

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Download this source code
https://github.com/ieee8023/PDFViewer on this source have function seaching text ob pdf file

Comment: Thanks, let me check

Comment: any easier solution? , as above library using ndk